# Not able to find frame name to switch to the active dialog window using selenium - Python 3.x

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, file-upload, dialog

I am trying to add a file in the following file input but I am not able to find the element (which I can see in the inspection as named "repo_file_upload").
I saw from other answers that mentioned to change the frame or active window, but I am not able to find the frame name or anything to switch to them.

Snippet of the python code

```
print(driver.window_handles) # Gives a list with only one element
driver.switch_to_active_element()
driver.find_element_by_name("repo_upload_file").send_keys("testing_automated_upload.txt")
```

The HTML element which has the file input element is as follows

```
    <div class="moodle-dialogue-base" aria-hidden="false"><div class="yui3-widget-mask moodle-dialogue-lightbox" style="position: fixed; width: 100%; height: 100%; top: 0px; left: 0px; z-index: 102;"></div><div id="moodle-dialogue-yui_3_17_2_1_1516089654562_333" class="yui3-widget yui3-panel moodle-dialogue yui3-widget-positioned yui3-widget-modal yui3-widget-stacked moodle-has-zindex filepicker moodle-dialogue-focused yui3-dd-draggable" tabindex="0" style="height: 558px; width: 873px; left: 164px; top: 59px; z-index: 102;"><div id="moodle-dialogue-yui_3_17_2_1_1516089654562_333" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="moodle-dialogue-yui_3_17_2_1_1516089654562_333-header-text" class="moodle-dialogue-wrap moodle-dialogue-content yui3-widget-stdmod yui3-widget-content-expanded"><div id="moodle-dialogue-yui_3_17_2_1_1516089654562_333-header-text" class="moodle-dialogue-hd yui3-widget-hd" style="cursor: move;"><h3 id="fp-dialog-label_5a5db137a26bd">File picker</h3><span class="yui3-widget-buttons" id="yui_3_17_2_1_1516089654562_403"><button class="yui3-button closebutton" title="Close"></button></span></div><div class="moodle-dialogue-bd yui3-widget-bd" style="height: 0px;" id="yui_3_17_2_1_1516089654562_708"><div tabindex="0" class="file-picker fp-generallayout container-fluid row repository_upload" role="dialog" aria-live="assertive" id="filepicker-5a5db137a26bd" aria-labelledby="fp-dialog-label_5a5db137a26bd">
    <div class="fp-repo-area col-md-3 nav nav-pills nav-stacked">


    <div class="fp-repo nav-item first odd" id="fp-repo-5a5db137a26bd-3">
                <a href="#" class="nav-link"><img class="fp-repo-icon" alt=" " width="16" height="16" src="https://moodle.cs.colorado.edu/theme/image.php/remui/repository_recent/1515344674/icon">&nbsp;<span class="fp-repo-name">Recent files</span></a>
            </div><div class="fp-repo nav-item even active" id="fp-repo-5a5db137a26bd-4">
                <a href="#" class="nav-link"><img class="fp-repo-icon" alt=" " width="16" height="16" src="https://moodle.cs.colorado.edu/theme/image.php/remui/repository_upload/1515344674/icon">&nbsp;<span class="fp-repo-name">Upload a file</span></a>
            </div><div class="fp-repo nav-item odd" id="fp-repo-5a5db137a26bd-5">
                <a href="#" class="nav-link"><img class="fp-repo-icon" alt=" " width="16" height="16" src="https://moodle.cs.colorado.edu/theme/image.php/remui/repository_url/1515344674/icon">&nbsp;<span class="fp-repo-name">URL downloader</span></a>
            </div><div class="fp-repo nav-item even" id="fp-repo-5a5db137a26bd-6">
                <a href="#" class="nav-link"><img class="fp-repo-icon" alt=" " width="16" height="16" src="https://moodle.cs.colorado.edu/theme/image.php/remui/repository_user/1515344674/icon">&nbsp;<span class="fp-repo-name">Private files</span></a>
            </div><div class="fp-repo nav-item odd" id="fp-repo-5a5db137a26bd-7">
                <a href="#" class="nav-link"><img class="fp-repo-icon" alt=" " width="16" height="16" src="https://moodle.cs.colorado.edu/theme/image.php/remui/repository_wikimedia/1515344674/icon">&nbsp;<span class="fp-repo-name">Wikimedia</span></a>
            </div></div>
    <div class="col-md-9" id="yui_3_17_2_1_1516089654562_707">
        <div class="fp-repo-items" tabindex="0" id="yui_3_17_2_1_1516089654562_706">
            <div class="fp-navbar bg-faded card m-b-0 clearfix icon-no-spacing">
                <div>
                    <div class="fp-toolbar empty" id="yui_3_17_2_1_1516089654562_515">
                        <div class="fp-tb-back disabled">
                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm">« Back</a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="fp-tb-search disabled">
                            <form method="POST" id="fp-tb-search-5a5db137a26bd"></form>
                        </div>
                        <div class="fp-tb-refresh disabled" id="yui_3_17_2_1_1516089654562_522">
                            <a title="Refresh" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm" href="#">
                                <i class="icon fa fa-refresh fa-fw " aria-hidden="true" aria-label=""></i>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="fp-tb-logout disabled" id="yui_3_17_2_1_1516089654562_517">
                            <a title="Logout" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm" href="#">
                                <i class="icon fa fa-sign-out fa-fw " aria-hidden="true" aria-label=""></i>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="fp-tb-manage disabled" id="yui_3_17_2_1_1516089654562_531">
                            <a title="Manage" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm" href="#">
                                <i class="icon fa fa-cog fa-fw " aria-hidden="true" aria-label=""></i>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="fp-tb-help disabled" id="yui_3_17_2_1_1516089654562_537">
                            <a title="Help" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm" href="#">
                                <i class="icon fa fa-question-circle text-info fa-fw " aria-hidden="true" aria-label=""></i>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="fp-tb-message disabled"></div>
                    <a id="fp-tb-manage-5a5db137a26bd-link" target="_blank" style="display: none;" href="null"></a><a id="fp-tb-help-5a5db137a26bd-link" target="_blank" style="display: none;" href="null"></a></div>
                    <div class="fp-viewbar btn-group pull-xs-right disabled">
                        <a role="button" title="Display folder with file icons" class="fp-vb-icons btn btn-secondary btn-sm checked" href="#" aria-disabled="true" tabindex="-1">
                            <i class="icon fa fa-th fa-fw " aria-hidden="true" aria-label=""></i>
                        </a>
                        <a role="button" title="Display folder with file details" class="fp-vb-details btn btn-secondary btn-sm" href="#" aria-disabled="true" tabindex="-1">
                            <i class="icon fa fa-list fa-fw " aria-hidden="true" aria-label=""></i>
                        </a>
                        <a role="button" title="Display folder as file tree" class="fp-vb-tree btn btn-secondary btn-sm" href="#" aria-disabled="true" tabindex="-1">
                            <i class="icon fa fa-folder fa-fw " aria-hidden="true" aria-label=""></i>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="fp-clear-left"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="fp-pathbar empty"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="fp-content card" id="yui_3_17_2_1_1516089654562_712"><div class="fp-upload-form" id="yui_3_17_2_1_1516089654562_754">
    <div class="fp-content-center" id="yui_3_17_2_1_1516089654562_753">
        <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" class="form" id="repo-form_5a5db137a26bd">
            <div class="fp-formset" id="yui_3_17_2_1_1516089654562_752">
                <div class="fp-file form-group" id="yui_3_17_2_1_1516089654562_714">
                    <label for="yui_3_17_2_1_1516089654562_715">Attachment</label>
                    <div class="p-x-1" id="yui_3_17_2_1_1516089654562_751">
                        <input type="file" id="yui_3_17_2_1_1516089654562_715" name="repo_upload_file">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="fp-saveas form-group" id="yui_3_17_2_1_1516089654562_717">
                    <label for="yui_3_17_2_1_1516089654562_718">Save as</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="yui_3_17_2_1_1516089654562_718" name="title">
                </div>
                <div class="fp-setauthor form-group" id="yui_3_17_2_1_1516089654562_720">
                    <label for="yui_3_17_2_1_1516089654562_721">Author</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="yui_3_17_2_1_1516089654562_721" name="author">
                </div>
                <div class="fp-setlicense control-group" id="yui_3_17_2_1_1516089654562_723">
                    <label for="yui_3_17_2_1_1516089654562_724">Choose license</label>
                    <select class="form-control" id="yui_3_17_2_1_1516089654562_724" name="license"><option value="unknown">Other</option><option value="allrightsreserved">All rights reserved</option><option value="public">Public domain</option><option value="cc">Creative Commons</option><option value="cc-nd">Creative Commons - NoDerivs</option><option value="cc-nc-nd">Creative Commons - No Commercial NoDerivs</option><option value="cc-nc">Creative Commons - No Commercial</option><option value="cc-nc-sa">Creative Commons - No Commercial ShareAlike</option><option value="cc-sa">Creative Commons - ShareAlike</option></select>
                </div>
            </div>
        <input type="hidden" name="itemid" value="708518204"></form>
        <div class="mdl-align">
            <button class="fp-upload-btn btn-primary btn">Upload this file</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div></div><div class="moodle-dialogue-ft yui3-widget-ft"></div></div></div></div>
```

[image]

Comment: Please read why a [**`screenshot of HTML or code or error is a bad idea`**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Consider updating the Question with formatted text based HTML and code trials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Saw in another SO post:

I did the following before searching for the element in the dialog window and it worked.

```
driver.maximize_window() //For maximizing window
```